MSSQL server, Partition table
We have LOG data, and I need to alter partitions by year, someone was did from 2013 to 2017. and I'm going to alter partition from 2018 to 2024. but in "testing server" I'm doing the partitions.  problem is when I'm doing partition just 2018 or just 2019, database and table is stack end blocking insert logs.. we cannot stop tables, or do midnight or... because the logs update very 10 min or 1 min or how to do without blocking "insert logs" ? I was did by index or
ALTER (or create) INDEX IXNN_LogTable_LogDate ON  dbo.LogTable 
REBUILD
WITH (ONLINE = ON 
        (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY 
           (MAX_DURATION = 300 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF)
        )
     );
GO

after steel ONLINE = OFF not ON, 

What can I do?
ALTER (or create) INDEX IXNN_LogTable_LogDate ON  dbo.yourtextLogTable
REBUILD
WITH (ONLINE = ON 
        (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY 
           (MAX_DURATION = 300 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF)
        )
     );
GO


after steel ONLINE = OFF not ON,
ALTER TABLE [LogTable] 
SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO);

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;
GO
BEGIN TRY
    
    ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [LOG_FF]() 
    SPLIT RANGE (N'2021-01-01T00:00:00.000');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
END CATCH;
GO


I'm afraid I really don't understand what you're trying to ask here. Is the code you have no working? Why isn't it working?

Do you mean that since 2017 all of the rows have been going into a single partition at the end of the table because no maintenance was set up to split partitions in advance of when they were needed? And you are trying to rectify this now? How many rows are in the end partition? Trying to retroactively add partitions for 2018 to 2024 will require data movement to the new partitions

If you only need to write to the log, you can perhaps create an instead of trigger which reroutes the inserted data somewhere else while you're doing your operation

the script what i wrote is working.. but question is what should I do in the script to prevent it from blocking?

@MartinSmith I'm trying to do by the script  "ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION LOG_FF
SPLIT RANGE (N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000');"

@MartinSmith I'm trying to do by  single partition  AND use the script
==  "ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION LOG_FF
SPLIT RANGE (N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.000');"==
but I'm trying with index or other settings or script. but still is blocking when I try alter log by Triger..  if you know how to do without blocking?  just only 2018 is more than 3 million rows are
2019 7milion
2020 10 million

Probably better to just create a new table with partitioning, copy old data and create an INSTEAD OF trigger to direct new writes to new table, then drop old table and trigger, and do a switcheroo with sp_rename. A clear definition of the existing partition function and the table indexing would help a lot, as well as explaining exactly what you want to happen.

that's is last what I can do,, but problem is I don't have big storage, this table more than 8TB

As i wrote, you can redirect new rows into a new table and keep the original one as it is while you repartition it

Buy a spare HDD drive, it's only a couple hundred dollars
